# Polymer 1.x: Example of sort used in dom-repeat

Tags: sorting, polymer, polymer-1.0

Please show code (ideally, a functioning JSbin) demonstrating proper use of the sort attribute in a `dom-repeat` element. [See documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#filtering-and-sorting-lists).

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#filtering-and-sorting-lists

```
<template is="dom-repeat" sort="_sortItems">
...
</template>
...
_sortItems: function() {
  // What function goes here?       
}
```

Also, [see this Stack Overflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905180/polymer-1-x-how-to-reverse-order-of-records-returned-by-firebase-collection) for more details on how I'm trying to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example with Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4hr7VaUmRDFuEXmMdMAk?p=info)

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items={{numbers}} sort="_mySort">
        <div>[[item.num]]</div>
      </template>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: "my-element",
        ready: function() {
          this.numbers = [{
            num: 1
          }, {
            num: 3
          }, {
            num: 2
          }, ];
        },
        _mySort: function(item1, item2) {
          return item1.num > item2.num;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Small improvement on accepted answer by using standard sortfunction notation (i.e., `a`, `b` variables and `-` subtraction operator instead of inequalities (e.g., `<` and `>`).

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f58W9AXJIXsHRUh3liY5?p=preview)

http://plnkr.co/edit/f58W9AXJIXsHRUh3liY5?p=preview

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sort</title>

  <script data-require="polymer@*" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <script data-require="polymer@*" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/polymer/polymer.html"></script>
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/" />
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html" />
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items={{numbers}} sort="_mySort">
        <div>[[item.num]]</div>
      </template>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: "my-element",
        ready: function() {
          this.numbers = [{
            num: 1
          }, {
            num: 3
          }, {
            num: 2
          }, ];
        },
        _mySort: function(a, b) {
          return b.num - a.num;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <my-element></my-element>
</body>

</html>
```